# Spring MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: spring

I write website, everything work, but when I add next page all website fall down.
And I receive this messages:

```
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/modalWindow.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/jquery-ui.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.validate.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/css/1/js-image-slider.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I try to add another page, but it's the same.
More over, I can't see all my images, website does not find path (backgrounds/phone32.png) in directory "static". 
I don't understand where I can  find the solution of this  problem.
this main page:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewMainPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This code another page:

```
@Controller
public class ClothFabricController {

    @Autowired
    private ClothFabricService service;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/cloth", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView seeCloth(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        List<ClothFabricDTO> dtos = service.seeAllCloth();
        modelAndView.addObject("allCloth", dtos);
        modelAndView.setViewName("allFabric/clothFabric");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

SpringSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/backgrounds/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registrationPage")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/testo")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/addRadio")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/cloth")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                //благодаря этой строчке при logout кидает на индекс, если ее удрать будет кидать на logout
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        httpSecurity.rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400000);


        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    //    JDBC Authentication
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //receive login(userDetailsService) and password (passwordEncoder) from DB
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new MyPasswordEncoder();
    }


    public IsAccountNonExpiredFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        IsAccountNonExpiredFilter authFilter = new IsAccountNonExpiredFilter();
        authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));

        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManager());
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/"));
        authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?error"));
        authFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        authFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        authFilter.setUserRepository(userRepository);
        return authFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepository;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had this same error today but I was working on a Wordpress site. It was using `gulp` for builds. I added a new file to my project and started to get this error. But then when I stopped gulp and did a `gulp build` then a `gulp watch` everything was good. Hope this helps.